# Is there a way to break a list into columns?

Tags: css, html-lists

My webpage has a 'skinny' list: for example, a list of 100 items of one word in length each. To reduce scrolling, I want to present this list in two or even four columns on the page. How should I do this with CSS?

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

I prefer the solution to be flexible so that if the list grows to 200 items, I don't have to do a lot of manual adjustments to accommodate the new list.

Comment: There is a library which does that - https://github.com/yairEO/listBreaker

Comment: I believe that CSS column option will do. This option is easy to use and change if there's a need. Here you have it explained in details -https://kolosek.com/css-columns/

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The CSS solution is: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

The browser support is exactly what you'd expect..

It works "everywhere" except Internet Explorer 9 or older: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/pdExf/

If IE support is required, you'll have to use JavaScript, for example:

http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Another solution is to fallback to normal `float: left` for *only IE*. The order will be wrong, but at least it will look similar:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/NJ4Hw/

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<style>
li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

You could apply that fallback with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) if you're already using it.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the top border on the first `li` in each column?

Comment: This works great for a fixed space, but becomes an issue with responsive designs since the columns don't collapse like when using display:inline or inline-block.

Comment: Interesting fact: IE is the only major desktop browser to fully support this feature without prefixes (since IE10)... Oh, the irony...

Comment: Microsoft Edge is the only browser (on Windows) that display lists correctly, breaking between list items, not in the middle of a item.

Comment: Chrome is **highly** buggy with this method when the list items are more than simple texts. (multiline texts/ellipsis/absolute positioned element inside..many scenarios). Firefox is superb. as always.

Comment: It may be necessary for better cross browser support to include this additional property `list-style-position: inside;` which specifically addresses the problem pointed out by @vsync I believe.

Comment: please check this issue with your code http://jsfiddle.net/pdExf/ if the list is dynamic it may cause problem when number of list item becomes 1.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you make a demo showing the problem? You've just linked my original code there. Maybe setting `display: inline-block` on `ul` helps?

Comment: @thirtydot thank you so much for your kind reply,please check http://jsfiddle.net/pdExf/902/ the list contains only one item but displaying as multiple item .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: Try `li { break-inside: avoid; }`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pdExf/903/. I'm not too familiar with CSS columns, so there might be a better way.

Comment: @thirtydot perfect :) I think you should edit your answer and include it, as it will improve the quality of the answer :)

Comment: @thirtydot why do we need so many properties? Why only `column-count` is not enough?

Comment: @greatvovan: This is a ten year old answer, you no longer need the [vendor prefixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) versions. They were needed in the past for multicolumn.

Answer (score 29):

### It's 2023 - keep it simple, use CSS `grid` or `column-count`

Lots of these answers are outdated, it's 2023 and we shouldn't be enabling people who are still using IE9. It's way simpler to use [CSS grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) or `column-count`.

The code is very simple, and you can easily adjust how many columns there are using `grid-template-columns` or `column-count`.

`grid` solution:

```css
.grid-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

`column-count` solution that maintains order:

```css
.column-list {
  column-count: 4;
}
```

```html
<ul class="column-list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
  <li>item 11</li>
  <li>item 12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me.

Comment: The order is less logical. Try an ordered list instead.

Comment: The _downside_ is that you have to give the number of columns. With the flex solution above the number of columns basically depends on the `max-height` of the container

Comment: @JuanManuelCañabate you can set `grid` to be dynamic like that

Comment: Is there a way to keep the list in order?

Comment: @DarkteK I second this question

Comment: @JRobz and @DarteK - if you're keeping the list in order I would suggest just using `column-count`, is there a reason to not use that? I've updated my answer to include an example

Answer (score 22):

If you want a preset number of columns, you can use column-count and column-gap, as mentioned above.

However, if you want a single column with limited height that would break into more columns if needed, this can be achieved quite simply by changing  display to flex.

This will not work on IE9 and some other old browsers. You can check support on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

```html
<style>
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap column;
    max-height: 150px; /* Limit height to whatever you need */
  }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very close to what I'm going after. The only downside is that the width of the columns doesn't adapt to the content (try with different length items). Not sure how is the column-width defined. Maybe the with of the first element? In any case, any pointers on how to overcome this?

Comment: Would it be possible to cap the number of columns rather than the height?  I need the items to fill into four columns, and the css `column-count` will do uneven number of rows within the columns.  Like 6 items in the first column, then 4, then 6, then 5.

Comment: Would be nice if you label the items eg "Item 1", "Item 2" so that viewers can see the flow of the elements

Comment: How can we target the last element in each column for styling?

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a solution that works in IE as well, you could float the list elements to the left. However, this will result in a list that snakes around, like this:

```
item 1 | item 2 | item 3
item 4 | item 5
```

Instead of neat columns, like:

```
item 1 | item 4
item 2 | 
item 3 |
```

The code to do that would be:

```
ul li {
  width:10em;
  float:left;
}
```

You could add a border-bottom to the `li`s to make the flow of the items from left to right more apparent.

Comment: while it might work for specific number of items, the result will not be pretty for just 2 items.

Comment: Another working CSS solution for the "neat columns": https://stackoverflow.com/q/54982323/1066234

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't necessarily *scale* but only requires minor adjustments as the list grows. Semantically it might seem a little counter-intuitive since it is **two** lists, but aside from that it'll look the way you want in any browser ever made.

```css
ul {
  float: left;
}

ul > li {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Column 1 -->
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<!-- Column 2 -->
<ul>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _Note:_ this answer will reduce the accessibility of your website for users using screen readers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The mobile-first way is to use [CSS Columns](https://devdocs.io/css/css_columns) to create an experience for smaller screens *then* use [Media Queries](https://devdocs.io/css/media_queries) to increase the number of columns at each of your layout's defined breakpoints.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)) {
  ul {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that (currently) Chrome (`Version 52.0.2743.116 m`) has tons of quirks and issues with css `column-count` regarding overflow items and absolute positioned elements inside items, especially with some dimensions transitions..

it's a total mess and cannot be fix, so I tried tackling this through simple javascript, and had created a library which does that - https://github.com/yairEO/listBreaker

### [Demo page](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/ORrJgz)

Comment: I prefer the jQuery columnizer plugin, in my opinion it had better functionality for what I was doing (was able to sort alphabetically, descending or ascending, columns count, columns width & more).
[jQuery Columnizer - WelcomeToTheInter.Net](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: @Brandito - well, the Columnizer code sure has more options, since it's almost a 1,000 lines of code, compared to mine which is about a 120 lines.. but does the job well

Comment: yes but my problem needed the list to stay as one list, what is more useful / needed depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can support it CSS Grid is probably the cleanest way for making a one-dimensional list into a two column layout with responsive interiors.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

li {
  list-style: inside;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
<ul>
```

These are the two key lines which will give you your 2 column layout

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: This is not responsive, when I use five column, it is not showing correctly in handheld devices.

Answer (score 1):

```css
li{
width:50%
}

ul{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>List Item1</li>
<li>List Item2</li>
<li>List Item3</li>
<li>List Item4</li>
<li>List Item5</li>
<li>List Item6</li>
<li>List Item7</li>
<li>List Item8</li>
<li>List Item9</li>
<li>List Item10</li>
</ul>
```

This is one of the simplest methods which you can just specify the number of columns need by changing the width of li. And making the ul display flex and just wrap elements .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

```css
ul {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
}

ul li{
    display: block;
    min-width: calc(30% - 10px);
    float: left;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n + 1){
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an unordered list in my WordPress site. For those who have been similar problem (making it responsive), the CSS is as follows. Enjoy!

```css
/*BASED ON THE ACCEPTED ANSWER*/
.elementor-icon-list-items {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 20px;
}


/*RESPONSIVE CODE FROM HERE*/

@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .elementor-icon-list-items {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 577px) {
  .elementor-icon-list-items {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 416px) {
  .elementor-icon-list-items {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="elementor-icon-list-items">
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 4</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 5</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 6</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 7</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 8</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 9</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 10</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 11</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>                      </span>
    <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">List item 13</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```