# How to split a list of links into 3 columns with CSS3?

Tags: css

I have a link list like that:

```
<div id="linklist">
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
  <a href="link.html">Dummy link text</a>
</div>
```

Now I want to have them in 3 columns with (in this example) 2 links per column.
I know that there is a CSS3 property column-count and such others but somehow the links are in one single row. (I'll add the `-webkit-` prefix if needed later.)

CSS:

```
#linklist a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89JKM/)?

```
#linklist {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
     -moz-column-count: 3;
          column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
     -moz-column-gap: 2em;
          column-gap: 2em;  
}
#linklist a {
   display: block;
}
```

The`CSS` `column-*` properties you have at your disposal are: `column-width, column-count, column-gap, column-rule, column-rule-width, column-rule-style, column-rule-color, column-span, column-fill, columns`. Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns).

Answer (score 0):

```
#linklist {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
}

#linklist a {
    display: block;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

should work, although I haven't tested it.