# How can i order an html list like this with css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

I want to order a list of items in this order (image attached).
each column should have 5 rows and then the next 5 gets another column and continue...

this list is generated dynamically via sql query with a loop on the li tag.

so i just need to find a way to order it that way in javascript or css...

[Example](http://statustimemachine.com/images/32fdsfsfsd.jpg)

Comment: You want it ordered by number like that? Or is it like that already?

Comment: its not ordered like that, this is what i want to do...

Comment: elements don't flow like that. Am interested in a possible answer anyway

Comment: Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/EV3he/1. If you could get the sql to setup the items like I did in a list and then split it, then this would work. I think I would also make a solution for making the whole thing dynamic and making seperate tables. + this is setup so it only works with the 15. I don't know how else I could do this though.

Comment: @Shawn31313 you just destroyed the semantics of a list, not to mention making the list read completely different for visual and screenreader users.

Comment: Depending upon what browsers you need to support, this might be helpful [How to split a list of links into 3 columns with CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235476/how-to-split-a-list-of-links-into-3-columns-with-css3)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at multicolumn environments. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) is currently a candidate recommendation, so it shouldn't change that much. Keep in mind that this isn't implemented in [IE prior to version 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), however there's a [JavaScript fallback](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn) which should work, even on lists.

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
</ol>
```

```
ol{
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Note that you have to specify the actual amounts of columns somewhere. However, if every record of your SQL query equals one item you can just use something like `count($result)/5`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EV3he/4/)

Comment: +1 you should add the non-vendor prefix rule (`column-count`) last though

Comment: @steveax: Already added this quite instantaneously after I posted my original answer, but I forgot to add it to the demo. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @codingbiz, I updated Zeta's fiddle - it now shows the numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/EV3he/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good example here.   http://www.alistapart.com/d/multicolumnlists/example1.html[enter link description here](http://www.alistapart.com/d/multicolumnlists/example1.html)

You can also create 3 lists that start with 1, 6 and 11. In this case you dont need css or js at all. Like this:

```
<ol start="1">....</ol>
<ol start="6">....</ol>
<ol start="11">....</ol>
```