# CSS – Single list with dynamic column wrapping

Tags: list, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: Ways to break list into columns on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page)

I was looking for this solution and couldn't find it so I thought I would post what I ended up making.

I was trying to build a single list where after the 5th item the list would wrap and move into another column. This is so it can be super dynamic with how many items the user needs.

[image]

Here is the solution I came up with.

```css
 li{
   position: relative;
   line-height: -6px;
}
    
 ol li:nth-child(6) {
    margin-top: -90px;
}
    
 ol li:nth-child(-n+5){
    margin-left: 0em;
 }
    
 ol li:nth-child(n+6){
   margin-left: 10em;
 }
```

```html
 <ol>
      <li>Aloe</li>
      <li>Bergamot</li>
      <li>Calendula</li>
      <li>Damiana</li>
      <li>Elderflower</li>
      <li>Feverfew</li>
      <li>Ginger</li>
      <li>Hops</li>
      <li>Iris</li>
      <li>Juniper</li>
 </ol>
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/im_benton/tHjeJ/

What do you think of my solution?? 
What is a solution that will work in IE?

Comment: Have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using the following as @tuff suggested.

```
ol {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tHjeJ/6/

Comment: Support isn't great: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: support is good, but currently Chrome is full of quirks and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that hard if you just want two columns
You could try something like this on your list:

```
ol{ width:300px;}

li{
  width:50%;  
  float:left;
}​
```

It would actually wrap equal number of list items in each column if li number divides by column number.

**If you want numeration to be like on your picture** you could use wrapping divs for each column and then use the `start` attribute on your list ...it will be something like `start="6"`

Comment: This only works if you don't care about list order. I only want the list to move to a new column if there is more than 5 items.

Comment: Read after the bolded text...use the ol start attribute. Doesnt this help you?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was looking for a way to do it without declaring a new div or ul. Turned out I had to just do it in the php logic which is probably a better solution at the end of the day.

Comment: yep, doing it in php would be easier and more browser compatible

Comment: @BorisD.Teoharov "Browser compatible", I don't equate these things, your not asking the browser to do anything compatibility related at all if you do all the work layout _for_ it on your backend.

Comment: The simpler html and css are, the more likely it is for any browser to render them properly, i.e. more browsers will be compatible with your layout. Is this clear enough now?