# Split Dynamic List into three columns

Tags: list, dynamic, calculated-columns

I am creating a product A to Z for a magento build. My code works however, the second column is larger than the first and third. I am missing a trick here and can't get my head around the maths. Can anyone see where i'm going wrong ?

```
<div class="content">
<div class="collapse">
    <?php $letter = $this->getLetter(); ?>
    <?php $_collection = $this->getProductCollection(); ?>

        <h2 class=""><?php echo $this->__( $letter ) ?></h2>

            <?php if( $total = count($_collection)): ?>
                <?php $break = ceil($total / 3); ?>
                <div class="" style="">
                    <ul class="">
                        <?php $i = 0; ?>
                        <?php foreach( $_collection as $_product ): ?>
                            <?php if($i % $break == 0 && $i > 0) : ?>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <li class="productno-<?php echo $i ?>"><a href=""></a></li>

                                <?php $i++; ?>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
                </div>  
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I have stripped out all no essential content so ignore empty classes and href

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing in php, you may want to output the full list and style it with css as described in [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page).

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3 it;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```