# List fixed number of items alphabetically in multiple columns

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items that I want to display evenly in alphabetic order (from top top to bottom) in three columns. Is it possible to manage this with css only?

With the example code below the three columns would contain following amount of items: 3/3/2.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="list_container">
    <div class="list_item">Adis Abeba</div>
    <div class="list_item">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="list_item">Beijing</div>
    <div class="list_item">Buenos Aires</div>
    <div class="list_item">Johannesburg</div>
    <div class="list_item">Mexico City</div>
    <div class="list_item">Paris</div>
    <div class="list_item">Stockholm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BERSp/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Ways to break list into columns on page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page)

Comment: No, the important part in the question concerns retaining the alphabetical sorting.

Comment: FYI: The sorting won't change and the solution is identical to the one you accepted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need column-count or mansonry javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/BERSp/2/

```
.content {
    width: 500px;
    border:1px solid #111;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list_container {
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -o-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
}
```

Javascript usefull : http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Easy as column-count wow! I couldn't find a solution with grid, flex box and ran my own javascript. Brilliant @G-Cryillus

Answer (score 1):

For the 3 columns, just set width to 33%:

```
.list_item {float:left; display: block;width:33%}
```

Comment: that doesn't achieve what he wants. he wants them ordered in the columns top to bottom, then left to right

Comment: Ok ok, I missunderstood, sorry