# Two column list with specific overflow

Tags: css

How would you create a simple html/css page that can display 2 columns with a list of items so that the first column fills up first and then flows into second column, *i.e.* NOT balanced column height.

For example:

```
------------------
1. John  
2. Alan  
3. Matt  

------------------
1. John  5. Suzie
2. Alan  
3. Matt  
4. Phil  
------------------
1. John  5. Suzie
2. Alan  6. Cathy
3. Matt  7. Bob
4. Phil  8. Richard
------------------
```

I've tried a div with a column-count: 2; but for example with 4 items it will separate them in 2 items in each column, where I would like all 4 in the first column.

Thanks!

Comment: here is a tutorial: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/ also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6509239/1582089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `column-fill: auto`:

```
-moz-column-fill: auto;
     column-fill: auto;
```

Next time you ask some question, share your code.

Comment: You have to set a `height` though, so this only works when the list items have a fixed (known) height

Comment: OP doesn't share the code, so I can't know how many pixels of height he needs. Imagine that each line is 20px height, this columnset needs `height : 80px;` and it fills like OP needs automatically

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect with @SimonPlus comment. I'll remember to share code next time I have a question!