# Divide list into two columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an unordered list something like this:

```
 - Item 1     |    - Item 4
 - Item 2     |    - Item 5
 - Item 3     |    - Item 6
```

I have this HTML:

```
 <div class="multi-column">
    <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
       <li>Item 4</li>
       <li>Item 5</li>
       <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.multi-column {
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap: 20px;
   -moz-column-fill: auto;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
   -webkit-column-fill: auto;
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 20px;
   column-fill: auto;
}
```

It builds the two columns as it's supposed to, but it puts 4 items in the left side and 2 in the right side (4x2). What I wanted is 3 x 3.

I also tried to use the *balance* value in the column-fill property, but it didn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I defined the height property and it worked. I's just me being stupid sometimes... but it would be great if we could define how many item should appear in each column. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: to solve your issue you can use `#multi-column li:nth-child(odd) { float:rihgt }` and `#multi-column li { float:left }` and `border-left/right`

Answer (score 5):

Give the multi-column class to the ul element instead of div and it will divide the li elements in the `<ul>` element into two columns.

```
<ul class="multi-column">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and add `list-style-position: inside;` to the css of **.multi-column** class.

Here is the link of the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/573mtbv5/

Comment: Worked in IE10+, Edge, Chrome but not in FF.

Answer (score 0):

The class multi column needs to be added to the ul, also you need to add the style below if you want to keep the bullets in both columns.

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/csfU5Xd0IaU8U9VKg5nS?p=preview

Comment: @HunterTurner - ***CSS Counter Styles*** are not very well supported (as listed on the page you cited) ... `list-style-position` is from CSS 2.1 and is supported by everything since IE 6, FF 2, Chrome 1, and my dog. http://caniuse.com/#search=list-style-position

Answer (score -1):

That is to correct code. By itself it works fine. Do you have any other code around that? You have included all the CSS for all browsers so I think there is something else going on that is making it not render correctly.

There is another answer at: [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns)

That basically does the same thing. If you only have one column you can't dictate how many items will show because they all will.

So I think the way you did it is the best way.