# How to align headers and unordered lists in 2 column div with css

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I am building a website in Squarespace and I am using a code block to add in a custom styled text block. It contains a h2, h3 and an unordered list.

I have got the h2 centred in the div, though I am trying to get the h3 and the unordered list to be balanced and aligned in the columns. I have included a link to my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/5k4mo3fn/29/

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS so sorry if this is easy to solve. I have done some further research and I can't find an appropriate solution. I am using Google Chrome.

I have tried adding code from this question:

[Divide list into two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160007/divide-list-into-two-columns)

```
    <div style="background-color: #98CB52; padding: 25px; border-left: 6px solid #19764A; column-count: 2; column-fill: balance;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5k4mo3fn/29/

Basically I would like the h3 and all bullet points to be aligned with each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks

Answer (score -1):

The `ul` tag has some `padding` by default. Reducing the padding will align the list with your headers.

I have added `padding-left: 20px` to the `ul` tag.

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/du4xmt3s/)