# Ordered/Unordered List on multiple columns

Tags: html, css

How can I split a single/one list (`ol` or `ul`) into multiple columns?

I saw that css `columns` property doesn't work: unfortunately, the new column is not interpreted as a new line, so the number (`ol`) or bullet (`ul`) of the item does not appear in the new column.

```css
ol,
ul {
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _“so the number (ol) or bullet (ul) of the item does not appear in the new column”_ – they are only hidden outside of the column. Set `list-style-position: inside;` and you’ll see them.

Comment: @CBroe, yes! thank you so much (admin, sorry for this _avoid_ thanksgiving comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns are still a bit buggy. Your example looks fine in Firefox (as long as you've added the -moz- prefix so it works at all). In Chrome, it cuts off the bullet/number as you describe—but you can add **list-style-position: inside** to change where it gets drawn. This works great if your list items are all one line, but it does change the appearance if they extend to multiple lines.

Comment: Also of note: in the future, your original example code should just work as-is. Unfortunately, today, we still have to wait for browsers to catch up.

Answer (score 4):

Vendor prefixes are important in this case. Your code looks different between Firefox and Chrome without the prefixes.

I believe the css `column-count` property is actually what you're looking for. In addition the `column-gap` property will add spacing between columns. As others pointed out, the `list-style-position: inside;` attribute is really what you're looking for.

It should be noted that this solution orders your list vertically so they read from top to bottom then column to column.

```css
ol, ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; -webkit-column-gap:20px;
    -moz-column-count:3; -moz-column-gap:20px;
    -o-column-count: 3; -o-column-gap:20px;
    column-count: 3; column-gap:20px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
</ol>

<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns

Comment: thanks. But, before Item #3, however, does not appear the number 3 or the bullet of the list ... (which appears only near first two item of the first column)...

Comment: sorry: my browser doesn't show numer/bullet, but they were, thanks (I saw them width `list-style-position: inside` css property).

Comment: I saw the code on Firefox, now: many thanks for your recommended code, now works in that browser.