# Is it possible to split a list into two vertical columns using only css

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

I want the following layout:

```
1 | 5
2 | 6
3 | 7
4 |
```

So the rule splits the column equally into two columns vertically without requiring a max height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```
ul {
    column-count: 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's like this:

```
ul {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

See an old fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pdExf/
Source: [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns)

Answer (score 0):

`column-count` is your friend.

In your case the following CSS should suffice:

```
ul {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count for further details.