# How to take an array of comma separated numbers and stack them so it renders in HTML5 as two columns of groups of four?

Tags: html, json, typescript

I have a group of numbers coming back from the DB as an array.

```
Like so:
<other JSON Data>,
[25484,25485,25363,25150,29548,29804,25606,29161,26229,27744,2733] 
<other JSON Data>
```

This is not a STRING... its an array of numbers.

I want to render the these numbers as 2 columns inside the COLUMN in the row.

I'm using Datatables.net 1.3.x

This is what it looks like coming from the DB

[image: What the Data looks like coming from the DB]

I'd like to make two column inside a column with the data stacked

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10
```

For example...

It looks like this...
[image: Example of my problem]

Comment: Make it an HTML list (using ```relatedCases.map(id => `<li>${id}</li>`)```, then use [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6509106/215552).